# How to traverse an Integer list and save starting&ending position of contiguous values

Tags: java

I'm trying to traverse a Integer list with size 1024 and the values inside are structured like {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1....}.

While traversing the list, I am making an object that saves the value along with the starting index position and ending position.

For example, the structure above will pull out 3 objects.

First object contains the value 0 with starting position of 0 and ending position of 8.

Second object contains the value 3 with starting position of 9 and ending position of 15. And so on. I've been on this for quite a bit and I'm struggling how to approach this.

Comment: `class PositionHelper { int start; int end; int val; }` iterate through `List` and create instances of this

Comment: I like how people say Stack overflow is not a 'let me do your assignment for you' service and still go ahead and post full algorithms for a question which is nothing more than a problem statement with no mentioned of attempts/thought process of the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

> While traversing the list, I am making an object that saves the value along with the starting index position and ending position.

Just iterate through the list and add new objects to another list along the way:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> newList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

for(Integer i : intList){
    int start = ...;      //your calculation to derive start
    int end = ...;        //your calculation to derive end
    int value = ...;      //your calculation to derive value
    newList.add(new MyObject(start, end, value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is keep track of the value you are at and when a new value is seen in the list, create the object and then reinitialize your values. Here is an example you should be able to apply to your problem -

```
int list[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
int currentVal = list[0];
int start = 0;
int end = -1;

for(int index = 1; index < list.length; index++)
{
    if(currentVal != list[index])
    {
        end = index - 1;
        System.out.println("New Object is S: " + start + ", End: " + end + ", Val: " + currentVal);
        // create the object here PositionHelper obj = new PositionHelper(start, index - 1, currentVal);
        currentVal = list[index];
        start = index;
    }
}

System.out.println("New Object is S: " + start + ", End: " + (list.length - 1) + ", Val: " + currentVal);
// create the object here PositionHelper obj = new PositionHelper(start, index - 1, currentVal);
```

Output

```
  New Object is S: 0, End: 8, Val: 0
  New Object is S: 9, End: 15, Val: 3
  New Object is S: 16, End: 22, Val: 1
```

Note

You want to account for the very last object in the list and you won't know until you have exited the for loop so that last statement accounts for that. You could also add another if check for the end of the last in the for loop. Dealer's choice! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
  static class MyObject {
    private int begin;
    private int end;
    private int number;

    public MyObject(int begin, int end, int number) {
      this.begin = begin;
      this.end = end;
      this.number = number;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "[begin: " + begin + ", end: " + end + ", number: " + number + "]";
    }

    //getters, setters
  }

  public static List<MyObject> traverse(int ... integers) {
    List<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(integers.length == 0) {
      return result;
    }
    int number = integers[0];
    int begin = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < integers.length; i++) {
      int current = integers[i];
      if(current != number) {
        result.add(new MyObject(begin, i-1, number));
        begin = i;
        number = current;
      }
    }
    result.add(new MyObject(begin, integers.length -1, number));
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> result = traverse(0,0,0,1,1,15);
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Output is:
[[begin: 0, end: 2, number: 0], [begin: 3, end: 4, number: 1], [begin: 5, end: 5, number: 15]]